# Use linux command in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, android-ndk-r7

I have build ffmpeg for android using NDK as mentioned [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/).

What I want to do is create a video file using image list as mentioned in [here](http://pr0gr4mm3r.com/linux/convert-video-to-images-and-back-using-ffmpeg/).

```
ffmpeg -i ffmpeg_temp/%05d.png -b 512 video2.mpg
```

I want to know how can I run this command in my C class file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

read the ndk docs

edit your Android.mk so that you produce an executable 'ffmpeg'

run ndk-build

locate the 'ffmpeg' executable on your PC ( will be in folder like ' obj/local/armeabi-v7a/'

use adb to move 'ffmpeg' to the phone - you may have to mount something in order to do this

on phone, move 'ffmpeg' executable to /data/local/tmp

on phone, get a shell and invoke the CLI expression like you mention:

/data/local/tmp/ffmpeg -i ffmpeg_temp/%05d.png -b 512 video2.mpg

it should execute on the phone like it runs on any other linux system

Comment: I want to use this inside my C class file.

Comment: procedure given applies as well to build where c-entry point is used to call ffmpeg from java jni interface.